# Q. Irreducibility criteria

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Show that $p(x)=x^2+9x+6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ according to the following criteria:

a) Eisenstein's criterion

b) Gauss' theorem

c) Irreducibility on $\mathbb Z_p$, $p$ prime.

$\textbf a)$ By Eisenstein's criterion, if we choose $p=3$, then

$p \nmid 1$,

$p \mid 9\  \ $ and

$p^2 \nmid 6$.

And so is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$.

$\textbf b)$ The possible whole roots of $p(x)$ are $\pm1, \pm2, \pm3$ and $\pm6$, as none of them satisfies the equation $p(x) = 0$, so $P(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z$, and so by Gauss's theorem, it is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$

$\textbf c)$ If we choose $p=5$, then $p(x)$ can be written as

$$\overline{p}(x)=\overline{1}x^2+\overline{4}x+\overline{1} \in \mathbb Z_5[x]$$

How $\overline{p}(x)$ has no root in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$ and $5\nmid$ dominant coefficient, then it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$. And so is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$.

Are these ideas correct?

Comment: Quite correct. I would just add an intermediate step for the last way: $p(x)$ is irreducible modulo $5$, hence is irreducible over $\mathbf Z$, so is irreducible by Gauß' lemma.

Comment: For $(a)$ you also need $p\mid 6$. For $(b)$ it's called the Rational Root Test, not  Gauss's theorem. in English

Comment: @Bernard thank you

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for the Heads-up. So by the rational root test, $ \mathbb p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z$. So it's irreducible in $\mathbb Q$ for Gauss's lemma. Is that correct?

Comment: @Manuel If a quadratic has no rational roots can it be reducible?

Comment: @BillDubuque I think not.

Comment: So  the Rational Root Test does it all.

Comment: @BillDubuque I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad all is clear